# Second animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

In an UL list do I want to animate the first LI inside. The first animation will remove the CSS class for the blue background and adds a new CSS to it to make it have a dark background. It also adds a new a line of code inside. The second animation will push the same div up with a fade on it so it disappears. Then it will get removed.

Both animations I have tested separated by commenting out the other animation and work proper.
The problem is that I can't run them together, if I do the first animation then the second animation won't work at all.

```
listTop = $('#ypPlaylist > ul li:first');

setTimeout(function () 
{
    listTop.css('background', '#2d89ef').removeClass('bg-color-blue');
    listTop.animate({ backgroundColor: '#1d1d1d' }, 300);
    listTop.prepend('<b>Running: </b>').fadeTo(300);
}, 1000)

setTimeout(function () 
{
    listTop.animate({ marginTop: '-=82px', opacity: 0 }, 800, function () 
    {
        listTop.remove();
    });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: "won't work at all" - What is happening?

Comment: The second animation is not happening. It should move the LI up and remove it but it doesn't. It does work if I don't run the first animation.

Comment: can you create it in fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What if you give different values in the setTimeout? And yeah, can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Ok so I have recreated it with http://jsfiddle.net/w4KYN/ and for some odd reason is it working then. Could it maybe be not working on the whole site I got setup because I got a script changing text inside the div each second?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate everything together, set a delay in between and remove the setTimeouts-function.
Checkout http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and  http://api.jquery.com/delay/
There is also a short example `$('#foo').slideUp(300).delay(800).fadeIn(400);`